# Why is my array going out of scope?

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, scope

This is for an emulator but right now I am just loading the ROM. I don't understand why my code is give me a break exception error. The gameBuffer variable is going out of scope after the bufferGame function. I can call gameBuffer[0] etc in that function but as soon as I make another function to call the array, it gives me: Unhandled exception at 0x0093303A in SNES Emulator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000008. Please help!

Header:

```
class CGame
{
public:
CGame(char* passed_gamePath);
~CGame(void);

void loadGame(char* gamePath);
void closeGame();
BYTE* getBufferedFile();
int getGameSize(FILE* game);
void bufferGame(FILE* game);
void printHexBytes(int offset, int amount);

private:
    int gameSize;
    FILE* game;
    BYTE* gameBuffer;
};
```

CPP file:
Constructor:

```
CGame::CGame(char* passed_gamePath)
{
game = NULL;
gameSize = 0;
gameBuffer = NULL;
loadGame(passed_gamePath);
bufferGame(game);
}
```

loadGame:

```
void CGame::loadGame(char* gamePath)
{
if ((fopen_s(&game, gamePath, "rb")) == 0)
{
    std::cout << "File opened successfully!" << std::endl;

    gameSize = getGameSize(game);

}
else
{
    std::cout << "Could not open file." << std::endl;
}
}
```

bufferGame:

```
void CGame::bufferGame(FILE* game)
{
gameBuffer = new BYTE[gameSize];

    if (fread_s(gameBuffer, gameSize, 1, gameSize, game) != 0)
    {   
        std::cout << "Read file successfully!" << std::endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Error reading file." << std::endl;
    }   
}
```

*Edit: Here is the additional code since you guys think the above is correct.

Emulator is instantiated in main. The constructor instantiates an instance of Game. Then printHexBytes is called which is where I get the error for reading the gameBuffer. (btw I have renamed game(the variable) to gameFile to prevent confusion.)

Emulator constructor:

```
CEmulator::CEmulator(void)
{

CGame* Game = new CGame("SuperMarioWorld.smc");
p_Register = 0x00;

}
```

Main File:

```
int main (void)
{
CEmulator* Emulator = new CEmulator();


Emulator->getGame()->printHexBytes(0x0FF, 9);

std::cin.get();

delete Emulator;
return 0;
}
```

Print Hex Bytes(part of CGame):

```
void CGame::printHexBytes(int offset, int amount)
{
for (int i = offset; i < (offset + amount); i++)
{
    printf("%X ", gameBuffer[0]);   
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not creating more than one instance of `CGame`? What does your main function look like (or whatever code calls this)?

Comment: The bug is most likely in code not shown.

Comment: The bug isn't in the `gamebuffer` variable. If you look closely at the debugger when the error occurs, you'll see that `this` is null. You invoked a method on the null pointer.

Comment: Nothing of what you observe has any relation to scope. The array in your question is dynamically allocated, i.e. nameless. Nameless objects have no scope. They can't "go out of scope".

Comment: How is `getGame()` implemented?

Comment: Hence my confusion. If I call `printf("%X ", gameBuffer[0]);` in bufferGame function, it works. If I call it in printHexBytes function, it doesn't

Comment: `CGame* CEmulator::getGame()
    {
 return Game;
    }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the `CEmulator` constructor:

```
CGame* Game = new CGame("SuperMarioWorld.smc");
```

You are creating a new `CGame`, storing it in the *local* variable called `Game`, and then throwing it away when the function returns. Perhaps you intended to store this somewhere else?

Comment: Wow this was it! Thank you so much. Game was the name of the class variable but since I put `CGame*` I guess that made a local variable copy of it?

Comment: It's not really a local variable copy, it's a completely different variable, with local scope, that also happens to have the same name as a class variable called `Game`. This is called *shadowing* and is usually avoided because it is confusing.